# Word for something that affects something else?

Tags: single-word-requests

*Affector* comes to mind, but that has different meaning. Also *influencer*, but that has too strong of an Instagram context. Usage examples:

> Alcohol is a possible **affector** of symptoms in Crohn's disease.

Comment: Would you really want to say that using an agent noun instead of just using the verb itself? Wouldn't you just say that *alcohol can affect its symptoms*, or that *alcohol can have an effect on the symptoms*? Nominalization seems like at best an awkward affectation for this context. What's the real-world use-case that needs a word like this?

Comment: Why not *cause*?

Comment: Did you try searching a thesaurus? 
What options did you find that comes close what you are looking for.

Comment: *Influence* is also a noun. But in a medical context you need to be clear what you are saying: what exactly is the relationship, how certain is it, is it causal or correlation, is it only significant in conjunction with other factors, or can it in itself cause something. If you don't know the details you probably want to reword to be as vague as possible.

Comment: **factor** can be used, i think.

Comment: _contributor_ to symptoms...